# Передача интерфейса из dll в основное приложение

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

Добрый день. Мне нужно из моей dll передать объект класса, реализующего такой интерфейс:

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
    void InitPhone();
    List<Phone> GetPhone();
    string Print();
}
```

передать в мое основное приложение. В основном приложении я так же описал данный интерфейс. В dll написан вот такой код который возвращает реализацию данного интерфейса:

```
public class CreateInstance
{
    public IDataProvider GetDataProvider()
    {
        IDataProvider provider = new DataProvider();
        return provider;
    }
}
```

А в основном приложении данная библиотека подключается при помощи assembly meneger и вызывается, таким вот образом:

```
public class DataModuleInterface
{
    Object o;
    Type t;
    Assembly ass;
    public DataModuleInterface()
    {
        var binFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Neoniklain\Source\Repos\KemSU_Shedule\Shedule\Shedule\Modules"));

        foreach (var file in binFolder.GetFileSystemInfos("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            ass = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(file.FullName);
            Type[] AssemlyResource = ass.GetExportedTypes();
            Type type= AssemlyResource[0];
            foreach (var item in AssemlyResource)
            {
                if(item.Name=="CreateInstance")
                {
                    t = ass.GetType(item.FullName);
                }
            }
            o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        }
    }

    public IDataProvider GetProvider()
    {
        MethodInfo m = ass.GetType(t.ToString()).GetMethod("GetDataProvider");
        IDataProvider res = (IDataProvider)m.Invoke(o, null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Ошибка возникает вот в этом месте:

```
IDataProvider res = (IDataProvider)m.Invoke(o, null);
```

И содержит следующий текст:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 
"Unable to cast object of type 'Shedule.Module.DataModule.DataProvider' 
to type 'Shedule.Module.DataModule.IDataProvider'."
```

Здесь стоит сказать что hedule.Module.DataModule - это моя библиотека, из которой я хочу получить тот самый злосчастный класс.

Comment: Ваш DataProvider должен наследовать IDataProvider, только тогда cast возможен.

Comment: Может вам есть смысл посмотреть как реализованы готовые клиенты подключения к СУБД, например [firebird](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/) уж очень ваш вопрос похож на написание драйвера СУБД используя "костыли"

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, он наследует.

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет, я пытаюсь реализовать провайдер данных в виде плагина, то есть будет возможно писать к моему приложения плагины описанного мной вида, при этом не важно откуда будут предоставляться данные из субд или веб-сервиса.

Comment: У Рихтера в книге CLR via C# (обязательна к прочтению каждым дотнетчиком!) описано, как реализовать плагинную систему (как уже ответил Igor, нужно определить интерфейс в третьей dll). Также смотрите [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

> В основном приложении я так же описал данный интерфейс.

У Вас определение интерфейса существует в двух местах, что для .NET означает два разных типа.

Поместите тип интерфейса в третью библиотеку и ссылайтесь на нее из первых двух.

*P.S.*

А кто из присутствующих когда-нибудь получал такое сообщение об ошибке:

> Cannot assign TFont to TFont.

?

Comment: спасибо за совет, попробую, но меня такое решение не совсем устраивает. Хотелось бы решить проблему без добавления еще одной библиотеки. Есть еще идеи?

Comment: @ВиталийВащенко Вы внимательно прочитали ответ? Может, я плохо объяснил, что у Вас в коде происходит.  Вас "не совсем устраивает", как работает .NET?

Comment: да, я внимательно прочитал, меня устраивает как работает .NET, жаль что нет других возможных решений этой проблемы.

Comment: Вам правильно ответили, если вы хотите "обойти" стандарты написания, и корячится с "ручной" линковкой - берите библиотеку `System.Reflection` cast делайте с `object` и тогда практически любые махинации позволены.

Comment: Кажется разобрался что вы имеете ввиду и как мне нужно сделать чтобы меня все устраивало, спасибо за ответы. Вы очень помогли :)

Comment: Как вариант - используйте один из стандартных интерфейсов, их много уже придумано, например `System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory` или посмотрите ещё DBCommand и т п, тогда вам не нужно будет использовать "ещё одну" библиотеку. На любой стандартный "чих"  субд есть интерфейс. DbProviderFactory - сразу заточен под "плагин"